# g++ how to solve warning "used but never defined"? (not static or inline)

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++

I have come across a strange compile error that I cannot make sense of. Firstly the error refers to the function as if it was in an anonymous namespace, however it is in fact inside `namespace database`. Secondly the "used but never defined" statement suggests that the compile requires me to define the function from within the header. The function is in fact declared in a separate implementation file. However the function is neither static nor inline so I am at a loss as to why it requires a definition in the header. It is a requirement that this piece of code is strictly compliant, because of this I have compiled with both `-Wall -Werror`. I have also included a shortened version of my source code for clarification.

**Note:** This question is different from other similar questions asked here in that it does not involve static or inline functions.

**Error:**

```
In file included from src/main.cpp:6:0:
include/database.hpp:19:6: error: 'void {anonymous}::SetupSettings()' used but never defined [-Werror]
 void SetupSettings();
      ^
cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "config.hpp"
#include "database.hpp"

int main() {
  database::SetupSettings();
  return 0;
}
```

**database.hpp**

```
#ifndef database
#define database
#include <iostream>
#include "config.hpp"
#include "sqlite/sqlite3.h"

namespace database {
extern sqlite3* settings_database;

void SetupSettings();
//   ^^ Apparent warning here.
}  // namespace database
#endif
```

**database.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "config.hpp"
#include "database.hpp"
#include "sqlite/sqlite3.h"

namespace database {
sqlite3* settings_database;

void SetupSettings() {/*More code here*/}
}  // namespace database
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by use of:

```
#ifndef database
#define database
```

After that,

```
namespace database { ...
```

is seen as

```
namespace { ...
```

i.e. an anonymous namespace.

You need to use a different include guard macro, such as:

```
#ifndef database_hpp
#define database_hpp
```